# Visual C++ 2008 runtime error-- debug vs release exe problem?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, opengl, debugging, pdb-files

I have a Windows executable (native, not .Net) project that I'm trying to pass along to a new team member.  It's a graphics modeling tool that uses the Qt widget library and OpenGL.

The project runs fine on my box but when we buld and link it on this new member's machine and he tries deubugging it, here's what he sees (not all entries included, for brevity):

> > ModelingTool.exe': Loaded
> >     'C:\ModelingTool\ModelingTool\ModelingTool\Debug\ModelingTool.exe', Symbols
> >     loaded.
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or
> >     open the PDB file
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find
> >     or open the PDB file
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll', Cannot find
> >     or open the PDB file
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find
> >     or open the PDB file
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find
> >     or open the PDB file
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Qt\4.2.2\bin\Qt3Supportd4.dll', Symbols
> >     loaded.
> >     'ModelingTool.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Spyware Doctor\smum32.dll',
> >     Binary was not built with debug information.
> >     Debugger:: An unhandled non-continuable exception was thrown during
> >     process load
> >     The program '[5936] ModelingTool.exe: Native' has exited with code
> >     -1072365566 (0xc0150002).

Would anyone care to guess what's wrong here?  Some sort of debug-release mismatch perhaps?

Comment: did you try breaking in debugger when exception is thrown? If not enable them by pressing Ctrl + Alt + E and then enable all exceptions. So when the exception is thrown you will get to see the callstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit code provides a good hint, 0xc0150002 = STATUS_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX, "Windows was not able to process the application binding information. Please refer to your System Event Log for further information."

The event log will tell you what is wrong with the manifest or what side-by-side installed component is missing from your machine.

Comment: Thanks-- I'll ask my friend to check the logs.  I'll let you know what he finds.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this before and it was related to different versions of the DLL's / CRT.

Manually remove all of the output files and do a clean build.

However it may be related to manifests, so check the points made in this [explanation of manifests and incompatibilities](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=408061).